# JavaScript command: »If div width <500px ...«

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

I work with a mixture between [jQuery Splitter](http://plugins.jquery.com/splitter/) and [Masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/).

A part of my code is:

```
var splitter = $('#main_container').split({
orientation: 'vertical',
limit: 100,
position: s1+'px',
onDrag: function(event) {
setCookie("left", splitter.position() );
Splitter();
$('.grid').masonry({
itemSelector: '.grid-item',
percentPosition: true,
horizontalOrder: false
});
}
});

Splitter();
function Splitter(){
if( splitter.position() <500){
$('.grid-item').css("width", "100%");
$('#show_all').fadeOut();
}
else{
$('.grid-item').css("width", "33.3333%");
$('#show_all').fadeIn();
}
}
```

And I need a command like this:
»**If the container *#container* (with a flexible width) is <500px wide, the position has to be again on *position: '50%'* width the *limit: 300*.**«

How is that possible?
Would be so thankful for help! <3

//

EDIT: Something like »**Reload the page if *#container* is <500px wide**« would be also okay.

I tried this:

```
function refreshPage() {
if ($('#container').width() < 900);
}
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reload the page if the container is less than 500px wide try:

```
setInterval(function(){
  if($("#container").width < 500){
    location.reload()
  }
}, 100);
```

This sets a timer to happen 10 times a second that checks if the container width is less than 500, if it is less than 500, it will reload the page.